# No Route error from Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl chapter 8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, railstutorial.org

I am studying Ruby on rails by Michael Hartl. I am stuck at the section [8.1.4](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#sec%3areviewing_form_submission) which is implementing a sign-in page using Rails 3.2.3 with Ruby 1.9.3-p125.

I have created a session controller, and I want my session controller's `create` action maps to this route `/sessions` , but always a routing error. Any clues? The following are my relevant files:

routes.rb

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :users
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

  root to: 'static_pages#home'

  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete

  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact' 
end
```

and my `rake routes` :

```
      users GET    /users(.:format)          users#index
            POST   /users(.:format)          users#create
   new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)      users#new
  edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) users#edit
       user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      users#show
            PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
            DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      users#destroy
   sessions POST   /sessions(.:format)       sessions#create
new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)   sessions#new
    session DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)   sessions#destroy
       root        /                         static_pages#home
     signup        /signup(.:format)         users#new
     signin        /signin(.:format)         sessions#new
    signout DELETE /signout(.:format)        sessions#destroy
       help        /help(.:format)           static_pages#help
      about        /about(.:format)          static_pages#about
    contact        /contact(.:format)        static_pages#contact
```

my `app/views/sessions/new.html.erb` :

```
  <%= provide(:title, 'Sign in') %>
  <h1>Sign in</h1>

 <div class="row">
 <div class="span6 offset3">
   <%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path) do |f| %>

     <%= f.label :email %>
     <%= f.text_field :email %>

     <%= f.label :password %>
     <%= f.password_field :password %>

     <%= f.submit "Sign in", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
   <% end %>

   <p>New user? <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path %></p>
 </div>
```

my sessions controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    render 'new'
  end

  def destroy
  end
end
```

In [figure 8.5](http://railstutorial.org/images/figures/initial_failed_signin_rails_3_bootstrap-full.png) the picture shows the url for sign in is http://localhost:3000/sessions. When I navigate to that page,

I always get a

```
Routing Error
    No route matches [GET] "/sessions"
```

### solved

The figure 8.5 is showing the page after you hit the create button, and the url changes from `/sessions/new` or `/signin` to `/sessions`, So it's nothing wrong with my above files.

Comment: You can add your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's a typo. You have to naviagte to `http://localhost:3000/sessions/new` as indicated in your routes.